# user is being created with Membership.CreateUser and when I pass the line it is being automatically deleted from table

Tags: asp.net, membership, createuser

I'm trying to create a user using Membership.CreateUser. After I pass the following line:
            MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(_UserName, _Password, _UserName);

I check the 'aspnet_Membership' table and I find out that the user is indeed created. At that point I stop the application and I check the table again. Mysteriously the user that has just been created is dissapeared.

Does anyone understands what's going on?

Thanks a lot,
Assaf.

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess, but it sounds like an error is occuring and a transaction rollback is occurring.

Check for a [MembershipCreateUserException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipcreateuserexception.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. However, I do check it and there is no exception raised. Any other ideas?
By the way, i should mention that this function has been working up until now. hmm... maybe it is worth mentioning that in the last hour I was twicking the membership parameters so that password will not be hashed, i.e., passwordFormat="Clear"
.